# Looping time values in a select element in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So i have this select box i've made in PHP which is a dropdown of time from 9:00 to 19:00 which is generated in a For-loop. which i use to pass the selected time value to the DB.

However I've been trying to do this in Vue for 3-4 days now, but haven't been able to find anything that helps with this particular problem.

This is what I have so far:

```
<template>
<v-col cols="12">
    <v-card>
        <v-row>
            <v-col>
                <h3>Pick your time.</h3>
                <select name="option">
                    <option value="Current Time">Current Time</option>
                    <option v-bind:key="i.id" v-for="i in 10" :value="i">{{ i }}</option>
            
                </select></v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-card>
    </v-col>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    methods: {
        timeInt() {
            for(i = 900; i<= 1900; i+=100){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

That last part in methods is me trying to write the loop in a script instead. i don't know if this is the right "Vue-practice" or how to bind that to my select element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm still not sure what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to create a for loop for a select-dropdown that generates time from 9:00 to 19:00 in Vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<v-col cols="12">
    <v-card>
        <v-row>
            <v-col>
                <h3>Pick your time.</h3>
                <select name="option" v-model="form.time">
                    <option value="Current Time">Current Time</option>
                    <option v-bind:key="i.id" v-for="i in 11" :value="(i+8) + ':00'"> {{ `${i+8}:00` }}</option>

                </select></v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-card>
</v-col>
<script>
    data(){
        return {
            form:{
               time:null
            }
        }
    },
</script>
```

Comment: Getting various errors with this one. 1st `unexpected token at data: () `If i remove that i get `Raw expression: :value="${i+8}:00"`

Comment: If the solution worked, please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting an error at `data: ()` but when i remove it i does work. however 1 small question. how do i post the value from the select? do i need to use V-model on the select element? PS: I'm using Axios

Comment: it should be data() not data:()

Comment: What is the backend technology you are using?

Comment: That was a typo, i meant data() . Im using Vuetify, Vuex and Webpack. if thats what youre asking.

Comment: No im asking about the server side where you are posting your data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223020/discussion-between-faran-ali-and-user10515430).

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
<div>
    <select v-model="selected" @change="changeSelected">
        <option value="Current Time">Current Time</option>
        <option :key="index" v-for="(i,index) in 11" :value="(i+8 >=10 ? String(i+8) : '0'+(i+8)) +':00' ">{{ (i+8 >=10 ? i+8 : '0'+(i+8) )+':00' }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
data(){
      return{
        selected: 'Current Time'
    }
 },
 methods :{
     changeSelected(){
            console.log(this.selected)
     }
 }
}
</script>
```